# Can't remove relation Parse Server Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-server

To create a relation I use this code and the relation is created.

```dart
  Future<void> followUser(uid) async {
    var user = await UserModel.getObject(uid);
    var currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
    final relation = currentUser?.getRelation('subscribes');
    relation?.add(user.result);
    await currentUser?.save();
  }
```

To remove a relation, I use a similar code, only I replace "add" with "remove".

But the relation is not removed. And the following message appears in the parse-server logs: "Uncaught internal server error. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')"

Comment: Could you share the code that you are actually using to remove and also the complete error stack?